# Retrofit doesn't trigger onError when using custom ErrorHandler

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit 1.9.0, RxJava 1.0.10, RxAndroid 0.24.0 and OkHttp 2.4.0. When I'm setting custom ErrorHandler RxJava Subscriber methods aren't triggered. Why? Is it possible to change this behaviour?

I'm attaching source code.

Initialization:

HttpClient:

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
httpClient.setHostnameVerifier(...); // allow all

try {
    httpClient.setSslSocketFactory(...);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

RestAdapter:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(BASE_API_URL)
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
    .setClient(httpClient)
    .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Accept-Language", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        }
    })
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler(this))
    .build();

Api api = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
```

Custom ErrorHandler:

```
public class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    private final Context mContext;

    public UniversalErrorHandler(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
        String errorMessage;

        if (cause.getKind() == RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK) {
            errorMessage = mContext.getString(R.string.no_network_connection);
        } else {
            if (cause.getResponse() == null || cause.getResponse().getStatus() == 500) {
                errorMessage = mContext.getString(R.string.error_contacting_server);
            } else {
                errorMessage = mContext.getString(R.string.unknown_error);
            }
        }

        return new Exception(errorMessage, cause);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Observable<List<Object>> observable = api.getObjects();
observable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Timber.i("onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Timber.e(e, "onError");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Object> objects) {
            Timber.i("onNext %d", objects.size());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't know about your issue directly but thought I'd mention that rxjava is at 1.0.12 now with different group and artifact ids. That version is a hell of a lot of bug fixes behind.

Comment: @davem - Edited my answer. I'm using RxAndroid 0.24.0 and RxJava 1.0.10.

Comment: How do you know an error happened? Can you simulate it?

Comment: I am using a custom ErrorHandler with Retrofit and RxJava and it works just fine. I suspect there might be something else, wrong with your code.

Comment: Could it be a threading issue? If you drop the `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` in your Usage part, does this improve the situation?
Retrofit will internally switch threads to a background thread anyways, so no need to manually `.subscribeOn` for just calling Retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed this line from the code listing:

```
Timber.e("Error: %s, %d", cause.getMessage(), cause.getResponse().getStatus());
```

`getStatus()` was causing `NullPointerException` because response was null... I overlooked it because there wasn't any log in logcat.

`onError()` will not be invoked if runtime exception is thrown from `handleError()` method.